# Displaying furigana (phonetic readings of kanji characters) in textbox/richtextbox elements

Tags: c#, winforms, text, ruby-characters

How would I go about displaying furigana above kanji characters in a textbox based element?

I've tried looking extensively on the web for information regarding furigana display in Windows forms elements - there appears to be some implementation for Microsoft Access form controls, but these do not seem to be accessible in a non-Access project.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the user entering Kanji and you want to display the corresponding Furigana?  Or do you already have both and you want to display one over the other?

Comment: I wish to analyse each kanji on a case-by-case basis and display the corresponding furigana above it as is done in Japanese print and media

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd need to implement or otherwise extend the existing IME - check the solutions for this question:

[Getting more data from the Japanese IME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095535/getting-more-data-from-the-japanese-ime)

Answer (score 0):

ImmGetCompositionString is the method to get typed kana from IME ( http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/875imeyomi/imeyomi.html [ja])

If you are okay with the guessing furigana from already-converted kanji, you may use [mecab](http://code.google.com/p/mecab/) or other library, but in that case, furigana are not always correct.